Which zeros of $z^4+6z^2+13=0$ are in the upper half plane?
I want to calculate $\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{x^4+6x^2+13} dx$ using residue theorem.
Consider $f(z)=\frac{z^2}{z^4+6z^2+13}$, so I need to find the zeros of $z^4+6z^2+13=0$ which are in the upper half plane.
Four zeros are:
$$z_1=\sqrt{-3+2i},z_2=-\sqrt{-3+2i},z_3=\sqrt{-3-2i},z_4=-\sqrt{-3-2i}$$
then I need to know which zeros of $z^4+6z^2+13=0$ are in the upper half plane.
we define that $z^{\frac{1}{2}}=|z|^{\frac{1}{2}}e^{\frac{i\theta}{2}}$, where $ 0\leq\theta=\arg z \leq2\pi$.
then consider four quadrants I, II, III, IV.
then we have
$$
\begin{align*}
-3+2i \in \text{II} &\Rightarrow \sqrt{-3+2i} \in \text{I}, -\sqrt{-3+2i} \in \text{III}\\
-3-2i \in \text{III} &\Rightarrow \sqrt{-3-2i} \in \text{II}, -\sqrt{-3-2i} \in \text{IV}
\end{align*}
$$
so the demanded zeros are $\sqrt{-3+2i},\sqrt{-3-2i}$, but is not right.
I draw the point in Geogebra, the answer is $\sqrt{-3+2i},-\sqrt{-3-2i}$.
I don't know where I make a mistake.
Remark: different definition of $z^{\frac{1}{2}}$ may lead to different output?

For the standard definition that Geogebra probably uses, you have $-\pi < arg(z) \leq \pi$.

This may not interest you, but your integral is easy with Glasser's master theorem.

What you can do is convert $\sqrt{a+bi}$ to $a+bi$ by following the method seen here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4396113/converting-sqrt-sqrti-into-the-form-of-abi-with-a-system-of-equations

The issue is a matter of how you define the square root, which is ambiguous because $$f : \mathbb C \to \mathbb C, \quad f(z) = z^{1/2}$$ is a one-to-two mapping.  It may be "obvious" from experience with the real numbers that when $z > 0$, the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z}$ indicates the "positive" square root, and this still seems fine even when $z$ is complex with $\arg(z) \in [0, \pi)$, but it is not all obvious what one means by writing $\sqrt{-3-2i}$, because on the one hand, you could mean $-\pi < \arg(-3-2i) < 0$, or you could mean $\pi < \arg(-3-2i) < 3\pi/2$, and halving the argument in each case identifies the square root in one of the two opposing quadrants.
To illustrate, consider a case where $z$ has a Gaussian integer square root, say $z = 3 - 4i$.  We can see there are two complex numbers whose square is $z$:
$$(2-i)^2 = (-2+i)^2 = 3-4i.$$
If I write $\sqrt{3-4i}$, which of these two square roots do I mean?  Should it be $2-i$ or $-2+i$?
Without a choice of branch cut, such notation remains ambiguous and unresolved.  Most computer algebra programs will choose the branch cut to be the negative real axis, that is to say, $-\pi < \arg z \le \pi$, in which case, $\sqrt{-3-2i}$ will be in quadrant IV, not II, because the program chooses $\arg(-3-2i) < 0$.
To avoid such ambiguity in your particular application, what you can do instead is explicitly provide a polar form, say $$r = 13^{1/4}, \quad \theta = \frac{\pi - \arctan \frac{2}{3}}{2} \in [0,\pi/2]$$ then characterize the roots using these; e.g.,
$$z_1 = re^{i\theta}, \quad z_2 = -\bar z_1, \quad z_3 = -z_1, \quad z_4 = \bar z_1,$$ and now there is no ambiguity where the roots lie:  each numbered root belongs in the respective numbered quadrant.

So if I choose $ - \pi \leq \arg z \leq \pi$, then $\arg(-3-2i)<0$, then $\sqrt{-3-2i}\in \text{IV}$. And if I choose $ 0 \leq \arg z \leq 2\pi$, then $\pi<\arg(-3-2i)<\frac{3\pi}{2}$, then $\sqrt{-3-2i}\in \text{II}$.

@Rogan That is correct.
